# Base de Datos Local en Java

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Quiero desarrollar un sitio web que funcione con MySQL, pero al mismo tiempo quiero que esa plataforma pueda ser usada desde un software de escritorio. Estoy haciéndolo con java, y soy nuevo en eso, quiero saber como podría usar **una base de datos completamente local** con java, que sea MySQL, de tal manera que pueda usarla como una base de datos espejo, de la que utilice el sitio web.

Comment: Te recomendaría que tengas los datos de conexión a la base de datos separados en un archivo de configuración y que esta configuración se encuentre en un jar separado. Así, solo tendrás que cambiar el jar de configuración de acuerdo al ambiente donde se vaya a desplegar el mismo artefacto Java (tu aplicación)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La verdad es que en el momento de desarrollo, la base de datos de una app web y una app de escritorio no se diferencia.

- **IMPORTANTE: antes de conectarte, debes crear una `BBDD` en `MySQL` con su correspondiente user y contraseña de administrador.**

  *Si no quieres complicarte la vida usa MySQL WorkBench o cualquier otra interfaz gráfica*

---

**Registrar el driver** en tu sistema (**OJO: el jar tiene que estar en el classpath!!!**):

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Driver registrado con existo!");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("No se ha encontrado el driver en el classpath!", e);
}
```

---

**Configurar la conexión a BBDD:**

Con [`MysqlDataSource`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/mysql/jdbc/jdbc2/optional/MysqlDataSource.html) (forma preferida)

```
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();

// usuario y pass
dataSource.setUser("usuario");
dataSource.setPassword("password");

// servidor y puerto (he puesto el 3306 que es el std, pero cambialo sino!)
dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
dataSource.setPort(3306);

// base de datos creada
dataSource.setDatabaseName("nombreBBDD");

// crear conexion a partir de los datos 
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

Otra manera mas antigua es **usando `DriverManager`**:

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql:3306//localhost/nombreBBDD";
String USER = "username";
String PASS = "password"
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```

---

Una vez hecho esto, puedes **hacer una consulta** de esta manera:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TU_TABLA");

// haz cosas con el resultado!

rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

---

FUENTES [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2839563/6751395), [2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm)

Comment: No estaría de más enseñarle como guardar de forma seguro ese user y password y que no estén hardcoded. Pero buena respuesta.

Comment: @joc ¿Por qué usar una versión antigua del driver de MySQL? ¿Por qué usar esa "implementación" cuando la documentación claramente indica que no es un pool de conexiones real?

Comment: @PaulVargas tienes razon, me lié entre las diferentes fuentes que consulté y acabé copiando el metodo que me gustaba más aunque no cambié el driver. Mi pregunta es... ¿porque ese tonito en el comentario? Puedes decir lo mismo sin esa prepotencia y [**añadiendo algun link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808160/what-is-the-jdbc-driver-org-gjt-mm-mysql-driver-for) que justifique tu afirmación, sino, aún mejor, currate una respuesta.

Comment: Hay muchos tutoriales ahí afuera de MySQL y JDBC, pero la gran mayoría tiene muchos errores de diseño. Por ejemplo, permiten inyección de SQL, no utilizan un pool de conexiones *real* (p.ej.: `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource`, no liberan los recursos de JDBC debidamente, utilizan *idioms* anticuados a Java 7, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es una base de datos distribuida, los cambios que hagas en la BD maestra se van a replicar en la BD esclava, y las modificaciones pueden realizarse en varios sentidos, esto es un problema de BD.

Te recomiendo que [leas el siguiente articulo](http://basesdedatosues.blogspot.mx/2011/06/bases-de-datos-distribuidas-con-mysql.html), donde explican muy bien este tema y te ayudan a realizar un ejemplo.

Answer (score -1):

Si los usuarios son pocos y la db en local puede funcionar en modo lectura, te vale con configurar en local una replica de la db maestra que usa el servidor web.

Editado 26-09-2016:

Lo que dices se puede hacer, pero no conozco ninguna solución out-of-the-box. Yo mismo lo hice con una tabla de "sucios" con dos columnas. Una la tabla que contenia el sucio y su id. De esta manera podia encontrar los modificados localmente de manera facil y rapida, y mas importante, si hay cambios locales que sincronizar.

Comment: Sucede que yo quiero que se pueda modificar cualquier base de datos, y validando por medio de las fechas y horas, que el ultimo registro o modificación se realice en ambas bd;